# Google Play Closed Test Track URL not working for anyone

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-console-beta

We are trying to setup a beta program for our app (already published, but the new version will be a full rewrite), and invite our users via URL. We have setup a closed track Beta, we have released the apk, however the URL is not working for anyone, we always get the following:

> App not available for this account

> Your account isn't currently eligible for this app's testing program.

We have tried:

1. being logged in with gmail, our own corporate gsuite and my own personal gsuite
2. We have waited a couple of days to see if it was that the issue
3. created a custom closed track to check if maybe the old one being used in the past with some users was the problem.

Nothing has worked so far. It is not an option to have an open track nor an internal one since we want more than 100 users.

Any ideas about what are we missing?

Thank you.

EDIT: We have gone with open testing track. It works as intended. I am not sure if it is a problem with the console or with the feature: the link should not be displayed in the closed beta section if that is not going to work. On the other hand it would be nice to have a link to share the beta program with whomever I decide to (ie we created a QR code for several physical locations). The problem with the open track is that everyone can join if they scroll down in the store listing within the app.

Comment: Hey @alberto, any luck with that? I'm stuck here as well.

Comment: Hey @Gal sorry for the late reply, we haven't tried again, we settled for the open testing track, we are soon closing it anyways as we are going to do the final release